# Netbeans show changed files and folders

Tags: macos, netbeans

I am using NetBeans 7.2 on the mac. Previously I used NetBeans on a windows machine. There was a really handy feature that showed an icon next to a folder or file in the project/files viewer to tell you that a folder contained modified files or that a file itself had been modified.

This feature does not seem to be enable on my mac version. How can I enable it?

Comment: do you want to disable auto scanning of sources ?

Comment: solved now - see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it in the end. When I added my project to netbeans, I wanted the meta data to be in another folder. This causes problems with versioning. I scrapped the project and created a new one, this time with the meta data in the same folder as the source files. Now I can see which files have been changed etc

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean, because I never saw a similar feature in Netbeans – neither under Windows or Linux.

Changed files and folders will be marked with another color, when using some sort of version control tool.

Maybe you had installed a plugin for that job on the Windows installation?

Comment: Ah yes - sorry its been a while since ive used netbeans. It was marked in a different colour, but this could be seen in the project / file view right? It's not there on my mac version. May be that i don't have the correct plugin. Any suggestions which plugin I should use?

Comment: No, but as I wrote: you see this described effect when using versioning (e.g. SVN)…