# Netbeans shows all files as modified

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I am using NetBeans 7.2 on Windows. It shows all files as modified. But when I click on show changes it shows nothing. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netbeans show changed files and folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299795/netbeans-show-changed-files-and-folders)

Comment: The question is not duplicated. It works fine. Today I open netbeans and see it.